# Save a Sql file in pg-admin

Tags: pgadmin-4

I've have being trying to save an SQL query into a file in PgAdmin-4, but the save button seems not to get activated.

[image: error image pgadmin]

Comment: It seems I've found the answer. I had to add the intended path name in the path-link above. If you have similar issue, take note.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I've found the answer. I had to add the intended path name in the path link above. If you have a similar issue, take note

[image: answer/correction to the error]